# How can I load more than 2 sub-relationships at once in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship

I am trying to load relationships 2 levels down and it seems the `joinedload()` function limits me to just 2 at a time under 1 direct relationship. Basically, I am trying to get a `promotion's` `sponsor`, `type`, and `category`.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: joinedload() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Code:

```
matrix_engagements = matrix_session.query(MatrixEngagement) \
    .filter(MatrixEngagement.id > latest_goldstrike_engagement_id) \
    .options(joinedload('promotion').joinedload('sponsor', 'type',
                                                'category')) \
    .options(joinedload('player'))\
    .options(joinedload('user_coupon').joinedload('coupon').joinedload(
        'reward'))\
    .options(joinedload('kiosk'))\
    .order_by(MatrixEngagement.id.asc()).limit(10).all()
```

`joinedload()` function:

```
def joinedload(*keys, **kw):
    return _UnboundLoad._from_keys(
        _UnboundLoad.joinedload, keys, False, kw)
```

It seems it should take an unlimited amount of `keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a second line with the same parent relationship did the trick:

```
...
.options(joinedload('promotion').joinedload('sponsor', 'type'))\
.options(joinedload('promotion').joinedload('category'))\
...
```